# Can I Connect Azure Kubernetes Nodes to My Local Network?

Tags: azure, networking, kubernetes, routes, cloud

I have a kubernetes service on azure and it has own virtual network.My local network is using pfsense for gateway and has a public ip.Can i define static route between azure and my local network for communication kubernetes nodes and my local machines?If yes how ?

I know i can use VPN gateway or LoadBalancer but i am wondering about just static routing or some solution like that.

Comment: Do you want to integrate your local Kubernetes nodes with AKS? Or just want to SSH into the AKS nodes locally?

Answer (score 1):

To connect to Azure Vnet you need to have a VPN (Point to Site) or Site to Site or Azure Express Route. if you want to use a connection to a pod directly you have to use port forward or an ingress controller.

Comment: I just want to connect kubernetes node to my local kubernetes node.Actually it is not kubernetes related too much.Just network between 2 networks.I think it sould be possible with route public ip but i am not sure

Comment: Let me clearify then.I have azure kubernetes service with 1 node.It has its own network.And i have my own network on premise.How can i connect this 2 network without a vpn ? Normally we can do it with static routing.But in azure i cannot do any routing.

Comment: VPN or Hybrid Cloud is a must https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rslaten/2014/12/08/static-vs-dynamic-routing-gateways-in-azure/

Answer (score 1):

I found solution like that:

Bind an public ip to node interface.
Allow only my premise's public ip fr inbound and outbound.
Do the same on premise firewall.
Create NAT rules on premise firewall.